# how to show same Dialog in Activity and Fragment in Different situation?

Tags: dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am doing a sample Project where I am using Navigation Drawer with Fragments.When I click in row **item1** it opens Dialog **Fragment1** .In Dialog **Fragment1** I have a button .

My requirement is I want to open same *Dialog* which is triggred from navigation row **item1** when button in Fragment is clicked ...
I am using Following code to make Dialog in Activity

```
    public void showRegisterDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_register);
    dialog.show();
}
```

and following code to open Dialog in Fragment

```
  private void LoadFragmentView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            showRegisterDialog();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();

            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Fragment5();
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
I need some guidelines,thank you..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and got the solution.
You need to use callback method in fragment.
For this purpose,you need to use the following codes:

```
your_button_on_fragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           ((YourActivityName)getActivity()).showRegisterDialog();
        }
    });
```